# How to fix CLI load error : `require_relative': cannot load such file -Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've tried the solutions provided on Stackoverflow, related to this error. I have also tried a trial and error approach by rebuilding my gem and the error is still raised.

Error below:

./bin/coding-schools:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /home/Jenhop8786/
temporary/coding_schools/bin/lib/coding_schools (LoadError)
        from ./bin/coding-schools:3:in`'

In my bin folder my file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require_relative './lib/coding_schools'

CodingSchools::CLI.new.call
```

In my lib folder my file looks like this:

```
require_relative "./coding_schools/version"
require_relative "./coding_schools/cli"
```

Project Directory:

```
-->Temporary
-->coding_schools 
 ->bin
   -coding-schools
   -console 
   -setup 
 ->lib
   -cli.rb
   -coding_schools.rb
   -version.rb
-gitignore
-coding_schools.gemspec
-Gemfile
-LICENSE
-Rakefile
-README.md
```

Comment: Is your script running from `/home/Jenhop8786/
temporary/coding_schools/bin`?

Comment: Yes, it is Danh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `./` from the `require_relative`.  The `.` refers to your current working directory where you started the Ruby process.

You can use `../` to go up one directory if needed.

With your particular directory structure, files in `bin` (or `lib`) can load files in `lib` using code like this:

```
require_relative '../lib/cli'
require_relative '../lib/coding_schools'
require_relative '../lib/version'
```

Files in `lib` can load eachother with code like this:

```
require_relative 'cli'
require_relative 'coding_schools'
require_relative 'version'
```

If you are really making a gem though, I'd recommend putting every file in `lib` into a subdirectory with the same name as your gem.  That is the convention.  But after you do that, you have to fix some relative includes, so you should first get your code working and mark this as the accepted answer, then look into that.

Comment: Am I adding this from my Bin folder or my Lib folder? I am editing both individually, process of elimination

Comment: I will add my CLI.rb file

Comment: Please share the full path to each Ruby file so I can tell what directory structure have instead of just guessing.

Comment: OK, I improved my answer.

Comment: Hi! One of the lines of my code in bin/rails look like this require_relative '../config/boot' .  However, I still get the error bin/rails:8:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- D:/ruby/task2/crash-course-test/config/boot (LoadError)
        from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
Do you happen to know what other reasons could be? Thank you!

Comment: I think you should ask your own question so this comment thread doesn't get crowded.

Comment: @DavidGrayson you're absolutely right! I've already posted my question. So here it is (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70941417/bin-rails8in-require-relative-cannot-load-such-file-d-ruby-task2-crash).